# Why does menu transparency mess up my notification area?

Tags: unity, notification-area, transparency, globalmenu, unity-tweak-tool

I used Unity Tweak Tool to set the menu to be transparent but now my notification area gets all confused after it changes:

[image: menu transparency problem]

As you can see it looks like it's not clearing earlier images from the notification area. I can still see my battery charging behind everything, but it finished charging an hour or so ago.

Also, sometimes after Variety changes my wallpaper the old wallpaper is still visible underneath the menu.

Logging out and in again refreshes it and fixes the problem.

Anyone know how I can sort this out?